Can electrons exist in a superimposed state in an atom?
Can electrons exist in a superimposed state (where both spin states exist) in an atom that is not measured or do electrons in an atom always have a definite spin state. I cannot find the answer to this question anywhere and I am also wondering whether if they are in a superimposed state when not observed, does this change property of the atom when non-observed

Yes.  This is the basis of electron spin resonance.

Does the fact that they can exist in superimposed state change atoms chemical properties?

No. Anyway the question is rather meaningless because if you prepare the atom in an $s_z= +1/2\hbar$ state it is automatically  in a superposition of $s_x$ states.

I feel you are somewhat confused about QM. There is no fundamental distinction between "superimposed" and "definite" states. A "superimposed" state in one basis will be "definite" state in another (where the "superimposed" is chosen as one of the basis states).

@John I had commented this and then deleted it, since it looks like the OP might specifically be asking about definite vs superposition of $S_z$ states

If an electron is automatically in a superposition of its spin states - why do paramagnetic electrons interact but not dimagnetic electrons as electrons will be in a superposition of its spin states so their spins wouldn't cancel out unless they collapse into a spin state

@ChemLover68 The issue appears to be that just saying "superimposed state" is not specific enough, since any quantum state vector can be expressed as a superposition of some set of states

@ChemLover68 what are paramagnetic/diamagnetic electrons? Also, due to the Pauli exclusion principle, the electrons in a filled $s_1$ orbital are always in the superposition $|\psi\rangle = (|u\rangle|d\rangle - |d\rangle|u\rangle)/2$ where $u$ and $d$ mean spin up and down, respectively.

@BioPhysicist What I mean is the superposition of the electrons +1/2 and - 1/2 collapsed spin states - respective eigenstates of electron

I mean paired electrons when I say dimagnetic because paired electrons show dimagnetism and paramagnetic electron (lone electron show paramagentism). Also do electrons collapse in a magnetic field hence paired electrons collapse to form opposite spin states hence no magnetism and paramagnetic electrons collapse to form a magnetic field

The OP has an earlier question that is functionally identical: Quantum Superposition in an atom.


do electrons in an atom always have a definite spin state.

No, each electron does not necessarily have a definite spin state, in the sense that the total electronic wave function does not always have a direct product spin part.
For example, the two electrons in parahelium are in the spin singlet state:
$$
|S=0; M=0\rangle$$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|s=\frac{1}{2};m=\frac{1}{2}\rangle|s=\frac{1}{2};m=\frac{-1}{2}\rangle - |s=\frac{1}{2};m=\frac{-1}{2}\rangle|s=\frac{1}{2};m=\frac{1}{2}\rangle\right)\;,
$$
which can be written with less verbose notation as
$$
|00\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\rangle|\downarrow\rangle - |\downarrow\rangle|\uparrow\rangle\right)
$$
